# Get rid of url in WP twentyten theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In wordpress the default theme in v3.0 is twentyten.
I'm trying to remove the url box from the comments form.
Looking in comments.php there seems to be no reference to it, as has been in past versions.

How do I remove the url box from comments in this theme?

Comment: You might get a better answer at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/, than here - as there may be a way to change this without resorting to editing comments.php that someone over there knows about =) (wordpress.stackexchange.com is another member of the "family" that stackoverflow was the founding member of)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the functions.php:

```
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'filter_strip_url');

function filter_strip_url($fields)
{
    unset($fields['url']);
    return $fields;
}
```